# Drupal 7: Zen theme, display comment count on node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates, drupal-zen

How do I display the number of comments near the title of the node when viewing the teaser?
I want to make a little bubble next tot the title in the teaser displaying the number of comments.

Comment: Are you using views to display the node teasers?  If so, see my answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4678/tokens-in-views-dont-seem-to-work/19092

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can easily print out the number of comments by printing out the variable $comment_count. To print it out only for the teaser you can check the $view_mode variable before printing.

In your node.tpl.php (or if you have created a custom template for your content type such as node--[your-content-type-name].tpl.php, use that), just add something like the following at the position you want your comment count to show:

```
if ($view_mode=='teaser'):
   print $comment_count;
endif;
```

Don't know about your bubble, but if you mean a tooltip, I've always used qTip module for that http://drupal.org/project/qtip